# Compare 2 rows and show differences with column name and changed data

Tags: php, sql-server

We have two tables with same structure (MSSQL)
We want to compare 
(ID) 122 from table1 
with 
highest ID 122 from table2

If there is one or more differences, we want to show the name of the column along with the data it holds from both tables.

I do not want to list all the columns out, as there is over 150

Something like (psuedo): -

```
Select * from table1 
Select * from table2

Compare table1 (column by column) with table2 (column by column)
```

Show changes : -

'Name' WAS 'John' NOW 'James' CHANGED 3/11/2016 3.45pm
'Mobilenum" WAS '02373643743' NOW '0983783738' CHANGED 4/11/2016 12.46pm

Do not want to try triggers...need php code....
We should not need to give any column names as it should run though them all dynamically...

Comment: Surely PHP has some way to iterate through columns by index:   Column0, Column1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not want to list the columns - Is this table going to change regularly?
You can still create the SQL dynamically - but store it as a static string.
Lots of examples for this (hint use information_schema.columns)
If the tables are not huge then I would p[rob write a bunch of Tests (1-per column) and UNION All them together - Then only return the Data where diff = true
Eg

```
    Select * from 
    (
    Select case when ISNULL(table1.columnA, -999) <>  ISNULL(table2.columnA, -999) then 1 else 0 end as diff, table1.columna as Old_Val, table2.columnA as new_val
    from table1 join table2 on ...
    UNION ALL
    /* etc etc * 150 ... */
    ) as x

where x.diff = 1
```

Comment: The columns wont change but to hardcode 176 columns instead of dynamically doing it seems not right! Just scanning all columns for any differences between the two is what I am looking for... Thanks for your response....